# Does coverage.py show test coverage on python bindings properly?

Tags: python, testing, binding, code-coverage, swig

I'm interested in test coverage of my functional tests. These tests are testing module code which was compiled via SWIG.

I've tried run:

```
coverage run --source=/path/to/module/__init__py allMyTests.py
```

and

```
coverage run --source=/path/to/module/__init__py partOfTests.py
```

In every case it saved the same information even though the number of tests and amount of code they are using from module is way different.
It does not seem working as I expected but maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Can I find out what is the test coverage of python bindings code at all?

It does not have to be with coverage.py tool.

Comment: Run it in verbose mode for the all and part and add the command and console output for each one into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coverage is used to determine what proportion of your code is being tested. So two test files that are completely different in amount of code and number of tests may still lead to the same coverage data if they are testing the same parts of your API.

**Update:**

it sounds like you wanted to test coverage of the C/C++ code in your python extension DLL. Since the extension is C/C++, the coverage module cannot go inside it. What the module can tell you is whether each Python function in your extension gets called from somewhere in your tests.

That being said, any C/C++ code coverage tool that can handle dynamically linked DLL loaded **on demand** will be able to give you want you want. Ultimately, your script is run by python.exe which eventually loads your DLL. If the DLL is writen say in Visual C++ 2010, and you can find a C/C++ code coverage tool that works with that compiler, then you can tell Visual Studio to attach to the python process, and provide coverage stats for the DLL of interest (I've never done that but I presume that there is a way of telling the coverage tool which portions of the exe -- your DLL in this case -- is of interest).

So I would dig a bit into finding a suitable C/C++ code coverage tool for your C++ compiler. Like on windows this SO post [Code coverage in Visual Studio 2010 for native C++ exe/dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867591/code-coverage-in-visual-studio-2010-for-native-c-exe-dll) indicates there is such tool.

Comment: Hey, as I've stated above i ran coverage with two set of tests. And both of them gave me the same line coverage (number of tested statements from result has been the same).
So there must be somethin wrong because those sets of tests are calling different functions from that module.

Comment: Probably this coverage tool only check the init file and doesn't care about shared library which it supports. And when i call the coverage on this library straight away it obtains nothing. So I assume there is no possibility to test python bindings.No that I'm aware of.

Comment: @rusticaLimit What do you mean by test coverage of python bindings? Since the binding is C/C++, the coverage cannot go inside it. What the coverage can tell you is whether each function in your binding (python module implemented in C/C++) gets called from somewhere in your tests. Have you tried the html output?

Comment: My goal here was to find out how many lines of code are my testing scripts executing from that C library. Now I see its not possible thx.

Comment: @rusticaLimit Don't give up so soon :) I have updated, I hope you find it worth upvoting.

Comment: Yes its been helpful, even though I'm on Linux platform. Thanks

Comment: @rusticaLimit how can I achieve the same on linux, I have to test python c extension.(i.e. code in c and tests are in python)